# How many ways to distribute 3 red balls, 3 blue balls, 2 yellow balls in undistinguished groups of two elements?

Tags: combinatorics

If the balls and the boxes (the groups) were distinguished, then the answer is 
$${{8}\choose{2,2,2,2}}$$
If we cannot tell the difference between balls with same color, then we divide the above number by $3!3!2!$.  If the balls are distinct, but the boxes are indistinguishable, then the answer is  the first answer divided by $4!$.  What is the formula for the case when the balls of same color and the boxes indistinguishable? (Does it have a name?)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to permutations (A situation when you choose but order is irrelevant and thus you throw out repeats).